# Foreground service killed by OS

Tags: java, android

I have a foreground service which download some data from a server, the problem is sometimes OS killed my foreground service but the notification of the service won't be removed!

Any ideas on how to remove the notification when the service is no longer exist!?

Comment: possibly remove the notification in your service `onDestroy`

Comment: @tyczj I tried but `onDestroy()` won't be fired!

Comment: how do you know the OS killed your service?

Comment: @tyczj I'm not sure because I didn't stop the service so only OS can kill the service while it's operating...