# Android is killing my foreground service after Force stop my package

Tags: java, android, service, foreground-service

I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now.

I'm developing an app that controls call duration.

I receive a braodcast where I start a foreground service to hang up the call.

but after five minutes or more android force stop my package then kills my process which cause the service to crash -I think - (don't know why) with no crash message or any kind of error.

it just disappear.

And it Schedules restart but it never start the service again.

here is the logcat

```
 12-29 00:28:52.857 619-619/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping package club.androidy.callcontrolfree appid=10006 user=0
 12-29 00:28:52.858 619-619/? I/ActivityManager: Killing proc 433:club.androidy.callcontrolfree/u0a10006: force stop club.androidy.callcontrolfree
 12-29 00:28:52.894 619-619/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service club.androidy.callcontrolfree/.PhoneCallService in 5000ms
 12-29 00:28:52.919 619-619/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{422b1b18 u0 club.androidy.callcontrolfree/.PhoneCallService}
```

using `adb shell dumpsys` I got this which insures that my service is a foreground service with the right priority

```
*APP* UID 10088 ProcessRecord{41aefb98 27922:club.androidy.callcontrolfree/u0a10088}

user #0 uid=10088

class=club.androidy.callcontrolfree.AnalyticsApplication

dir=/data/app/club.androidy.callcontrolfree-1.apk publicDir=/data/app/club.androidy.callcontrolfree-1.apk data=/data/data/club.androidy.callcontrolfree

packageList=[club.androidy.callcontrolfree]

compat={240dpi}

thread=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@41cef800

pid=27922 starting=false lastPss=0

lastActivityTime=-11s768ms lruWeight=14097791 serviceb=false keeping=true hidden=false empty=true

oom: max=15 hidden=9 client=9 empty=15 curRaw=2 setRaw=2 nonStopping=2 cur=2 set=2

curSchedGroup=-1 setSchedGroup=-1 systemNoUi=false trimMemoryLevel=0

adjSeq=63108 lruSeq=10968

setIsForeground=false foregroundServices=true forcingToForeground=null

lastRequestedGc=-12s74ms lastLowMemory=-12s74ms reportLowMemory=false

Services:

  - ServiceRecord{41fb2578 u0 club.androidy.callcontrolfree/.PhoneCallService}
```

and in `Process LRU list (sorted by oom_adj):` section

```
Proc #24: adj=prcp /FS trm= 0 27922:club.androidy.callcontrolfree/u0a10088 (fg-service)
```

I'm not binding my service to any activities

I start my service like this:

```
            Intent srvIntent = new Intent(context, PhoneCallService.class);
            context.stopService(srvIntent);
            PhoneCallService.stopService = false;
            context.startService(srvIntent);
```

and this is my `onStartCommand` :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String txtNotificationTicker = context.getString(R.string.strNotificationTicker);
    String txtNotificationTitle = context.getString(R.string.strNotificationContexTitle);
    String txtNotificationText = context.getString(R.string.strNotificationContexText);
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(this, StopServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentCancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, cancelIntent
            , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Action action =
            new NotificationCompat.Action
                    .Builder(R.drawable.ic_cancel
                    , context.getString(R.string.stop_service), pendingIntentCancel)
                    .build();

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    int HELLO_ID = 1;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, HELLO_ID, mIntent , 0);
    this.mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    Notification notification = builder
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(txtNotificationTitle)))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(getBitmap(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(txtNotificationText))
                    .append(": ").append(PHONE_NUMBER).toString())
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .addAction(action)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(1, notification);
    this.pt = new PhoneThread();
    this.pt.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

I'm acquiring wake lock like this

```
        if (PhoneCallService.sCpuWakeLock == null) {
                PhoneCallService.sCpuWakeLock = ((PowerManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE))
                        .newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"CCF");
                PhoneCallService.sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
            Log.e("androidy","wacklock acquired");
            }
```

I have already tried many solutions from SO and google issues but nothing works for me.

I saw and tried all these :

[Foreground service killed by OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726829/foreground-service-killed-by-os)

[Foreground service gets killed every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471159/foreground-service-gets-killed-every-time)

[Android foreground service being killed under certain conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288717/android-foreground-service-being-killed-under-certain-conditions)

[Foreground Service being killed on Notification click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787601/foreground-service-being-killed-on-notification-click)

[Foreground service being killed by Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645193/foreground-service-being-killed-by-android/14293528#14293528)

Users who keep the app are only 30% from total installs.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

If you have the same issue please check **Power Saving Options** in your phone settings if your phone has this feature it will kill your app after the screen is off and will not allow it to work in background.

**Original answer:**
After a lot of search I solved it myself

it turned out that my app was power-intensive as shown in the picture below

[image]

Hence, android was force stopping it after 5 minutes when there is no activity on the screen to save power.

I solved power consumption issues and everything became OK.

[image]